# Open PDF intent no app found to perform this action

Tags: android

I am using this code to open PDF file that was saved in internal cache dir

```
private fun openPdfFile(file: File) {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(file.path), "application/pdf")
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY)
    val chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "")
    startActivity(chooser)
}
```

But I got - `"No apps can perform this action"`

I have apps on the device that can open the PDF file.

And File provider is registered.

Comment: `Uri.parse(file.path)` with `file: File` smells really bad - use FileProvider to get uri instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And File provider is registered

That may be true, but you are not using `FileProvider` in your code. You need to replace `Uri.parse()` with `FileProvider.getUriForFile()`.

You also need to take into account that not all users will have access to PDF viewers, by wrapping your `startActivity()` call in an exception handler.